# Contiki - How can I trigger an event?

Tags: c, contiki

I am trying to write a program in Contiki for Zolertia REmote, that will read a value from a sensor, and depending on this value and whether the user button on the remote is pushed for an extended duration, a led will be turned on, dimmed or will remain off. Part of the code that I have so far is this:

while(1) {

```
PROCESS_WAIT_EVENT_UNTIL(etimer_expired(&et));
ldr = adc_zoul.value(ZOUL_SENSORS_ADC1);
printf("ADC1 = %u raw\n", ldr);

if (ldr >= 16500) {
PROCESS_YIELD();
if (ev == button_press_duration_exceeded) {
    GPIO_SOFTWARE_CONTROL(EXAMPLE_PORT_BASE, EXAMPLE_PIN_MASK);
    GPIO_SET_OUTPUT(EXAMPLE_PORT_BASE, EXAMPLE_PIN_MASK);
    GPIO_SET_PIN(EXAMPLE_PORT_BASE, EXAMPLE_PIN_MASK); /*Set High*/
     }
else {
    pwm_enable(pwm_num.freq, pwm_num.duty, 0, pwm_num.timer, pwm_num.ab);
    pwm_start(pwm_num.timer, pwm_num.ab, pwm_num.port, pwm_num.pin);
  }
}
else if (ldr < 16500 && ldr >= 6600) {
PROCESS_YIELD();
if(ev == button_press_duration_exceeded) {
    pwm_enable(pwm_num.freq, pwm_num.duty, 0, pwm_num.timer, pwm_num.ab);
    pwm_start(pwm_num.timer, pwm_num.ab, pwm_num.port, pwm_num.pin);
    }
else {
    GPIO_SOFTWARE_CONTROL(EXAMPLE_PORT_BASE, EXAMPLE_PIN_MASK);
    GPIO_SET_OUTPUT(EXAMPLE_PORT_BASE, EXAMPLE_PIN_MASK);
    GPIO_CLR_PIN(EXAMPLE_PORT_BASE, EXAMPLE_PIN_MASK); /*Set Low*/
   }
 }
else { 
   GPIO_SOFTWARE_CONTROL(EXAMPLE_PORT_BASE, EXAMPLE_PIN_MASK);
   GPIO_SET_OUTPUT(EXAMPLE_PORT_BASE, EXAMPLE_PIN_MASK);
   GPIO_CLR_PIN(EXAMPLE_PORT_BASE, EXAMPLE_PIN_MASK); /*Set Low*/
}


etimer_reset(&et);
```

}

My problem is when the ldr value goes from, let's say, below 6600 to above 16500, and therefore the led should have been dimming no matter what. In fact, however, it does not dim unless I press the User Button, even for a second. Then as long as the ldr value remains above 16500 everything works well - while I am pressing the button the led is full on and when I release it the led dims. When however the ldr changes and goes from above 16500 to [6600,16500), and the led should be off while the button is not pressed, it actually dims until I press the User Button again even for a second.

As I see it, the problem is that even though the ldr value changes, it is not been read unless I press the user button. And I think that this has to do with the use of the command PROCESS_YIELD();, which tells the program to wait until an event happens. If I remove this command though, the led does not turn on or dim at all. So, my guess is that I have to trigger an event so that the ldr value is read.

Does anyone has an idea about how to do this? Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0):

You may want to use the following:

```
Process_wait_event_until(ev==XXXXXX);
```

Instead of `process yield`.